# how to get custom user class

Tags: symfony, authentication

Maybe the question is very simple but here it is :

I authenticated using my own User class and UserProvider class. I extended `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to modify the connected user.
It should happen in this method :

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
```

In my custom class User, I have a `addRole` method.

How can I reach this method from the token given as a parameter in the `onAuthenticationSuccess` function?

Comment: Not sure I understand... there's a `$token->getUser()` method, which should provide your `addRole` method right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to retrieve the authenticated User :

```
$user = $token->getUser();
```

Then, you should be able to call `$user->addRole()`.

But, you need to store the changes in db.
For that, you need to inject the doctrine `EntityManager` in your service.

Change your service declaration :

```
# services.yml
    your_authentication_success_handler: 
    # ...
    arguments:
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Set the `entityManager` in the constructor of your service:

```
// Authentication success handler
public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager = null)
{
    $this->_em = $entityManager;
}
```

Now you can update your User in the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method like follows:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) 
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $user->addRole('YOUR_ROLE');
    $this->_em->flush();
}
```

**Update**

Because the `User` returned is not an instance of your custom `User` entity, you have to retrieve it using the `Repository` of your entity.

```
use YourBundle\Entity\User;
// ...

$user = $token->getUser();

if (!($tokenUser instanceof User) {
    $repository = $this->_em->getRepository('YourBundle:User');
    $user = $repository->findBy(array(
        'username' => $tokenUser->getUsername(), // Assuming the 'username' property is unique
    ));
}

$user->addRole('YOUR_ROLE'); // Now you can access the method
$this->_em->flush();
```

Comment: $token->getUser() does not allow me to use addRole(). I have to cast right ?

Comment: I've re-edited with a check for more comprehension. Your authentication handler does not use your custom entity to return the user, also you need to retrieve the user using your own entity, then `addRole` is accessible. Try it, it should works as expected

Comment: can u write down some code because I just see $user = $token->getUser(); which does not work

Comment: I added the code, you should try it. If you cannot access `addRole`, it's because the result of `$token->getUser()` is not an instance of your own entity. I just use your own entity to retrieve the real user object which can access the expected method.

Comment: I know because of the IDE which shows me that $token->getUser() retruns a TokenInterface object... Maybe it is wrong

Comment: Yes, you should try it really, almost all classes implement an interface and your IDE will not return the class directly. Otherwise, the workaround in my update will works fine. Add your security firewall, your listener and the service declaration in your other question, I'll help you to make the event fired.

Comment: Plus, TokenInterface::getUser returns an instance of UserInterface or null.

Comment: IDE is wrong so... let's go to the other question and I can try